# Error: Using Spark Structured Streaming to read and write data to another topic in kafka

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I am doing a small task of reading access_logs file using a kafka topic, then i count the status and send the count of Status to another kafka topic. 
But i keep getting errors like,
while i use no output mode or append mode:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Append output mode not supported when there are streaming aggregations on streaming DataFrames/DataSets without watermark;;
```

When using complete mode:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException: requirement failed: KafkaTable does not support Complete mode.
```

This is my code:
**structuredStreaming.scala**

```
package com.spark.sparkstreaming

import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.log4j._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

import java.util.regex.Pattern
import java.util.regex.Matcher
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Locale

import Utilities._
object structuredStreaming {

  case class LogEntry(ip:String, client:String, user:String, dateTime:String, request:String, status:String, bytes:String, referer:String, agent:String)

  val logPattern = apacheLogPattern()
  val datePattern = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?) .+]")

  def parseDateField(field: String): Option[String] = {

    val dateMatcher = datePattern.matcher(field)
    if (dateMatcher.find) {
      val dateString = dateMatcher.group(1)
      val dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH)
      val date = (dateFormat.parse(dateString))
      val timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime());
      return Option(timestamp.toString())
    } else {
      None
    }
  }

  def parseLog(x:Row) : Option[LogEntry] = {

    val matcher:Matcher = logPattern.matcher(x.getString(0));
    if (matcher.matches()) {
      val timeString = matcher.group(4)
      return Some(LogEntry(
        matcher.group(1),
        matcher.group(2),
        matcher.group(3),
        parseDateField(matcher.group(4)).getOrElse(""),
        matcher.group(5),
        matcher.group(6),
        matcher.group(7),
        matcher.group(8),
        matcher.group(9)
      ))
    } else {
      return None
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName("StructuredStreaming")
      .master("local[*]")
      .config("spark.sql.streaming.checkpointLocation", "/home/UDHAV.MAHATA/Documents/Checkpoints")
      .getOrCreate()

    setupLogging()

//    val rawData = spark.readStream.text("/home/UDHAV.MAHATA/Documents/Spark/logs")
    val rawData = spark
      .readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
      .option("subscribe", "testing")
      .load()
    import spark.implicits._

    val structuredData = rawData.flatMap(parseLog).select("status")
    val windowed = structuredData.groupBy($"status").count()
    //val query = windowed.writeStream.outputMode("complete").format("console").start()
    val query = windowed
      .writeStream
        .outputMode("complete")
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
      .option("topic", "sink")
      .start()
    query.awaitTermination()
    spark.stop()
  }

}
```

**Utilities.scala**

```
package com.spark.sparkstreaming

import org.apache.log4j.Level
import java.util.regex.Pattern
import java.util.regex.Matcher

object Utilities {
  def setupLogging() = {
    import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
    val rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger()
    rootLogger.setLevel(Level.ERROR)
  }
 def apacheLogPattern():Pattern = {
    val ddd = "\\d{1,3}"
    val ip = s"($ddd\\.$ddd\\.$ddd\\.$ddd)?"
    val client = "(\\S+)"
    val user = "(\\S+)"
    val dateTime = "(\\[.+?\\])"
    val request = "\"(.*?)\""
    val status = "(\\d{3})"
    val bytes = "(\\S+)"
    val referer = "\"(.*?)\""
    val agent = "\"(.*?)\""
    val regex = s"$ip $client $user $dateTime $request $status $bytes $referer $agent"
    Pattern.compile(regex)
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me with where am i doing mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message is suggesting, you need to add a watermark to your grouping.

Replace this line

```
val windowed = structuredData.groupBy($"status").count()
```

with

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{window, col}

val windowed = structuredData.groupBy(window(col("dateTime"), "10 minutes"), "status").count()
```

It is important that the column `dateTime` is of type `timestamp` which you parse from the Kafka source anyway if I understood your code correctly.

Without the window, Spark will not know how much data to be aggregated.

Comment: i tried what u said but i got this error: `Cannot resolve overloaded method 'groupBy'`

Comment: so i tried, `val windowed = structuredData.withWatermark("dateTime", "10 minutes").groupBy($"status", window($"dateTime", "1 hour")).count()` and i got this new error. **ERROR MicroBatchExecution: Query [id = a640c0af-0a65-4c0e-8207-82a7c751d8c9, runId = 04a92687-1ca6-490d-8dad-591c3e649b5d] terminated with error
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Required attribute 'value' not found;**

Comment: Sure i will do that